# Remove text inside of text from a larger string with PHP

Tags: php, string, replace, shortcode

What I'm trying to do is, if it exists, remove an occurrence of text inside a 'shortcode', eg: `Here's some content [shortcode]I want this text removed[/shortcode] Some more content` to be changed to `Here's some content [shortcode][/shortcode] Some more content`.

It seems like a pretty simple thing to do but I can't figure it out.. =/

The shortcode will only show up once in the entire string.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$var = "Here's some content [shortcode]I want this text removed[/shortcode] Some more content";
$startTag = "[shortcode]";
$endTag = "[/shortcode]";
$pos1 = strpos($var, $startTag) + strlen($startTag);
$pos2 = strpos($var, $endTag);
$result = substr_replace($var, '', $pos1, $pos2-$pos1);
```

Comment: This **will not work** if there is multiple [shortcode] block. I put a solution below that will work fine for multiple blocks as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy to do with preg_replace(). For your purpose, use `/\[shortcode\].*\[\/shortcode\]/` as pattern.

```
$replace = "[shortcode][/shortcode]"; 
$filteredText = preg_replace("/\[shortcode\].*\[\/shortcode\]/", $replace, $yourContent);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php for more details.

Answer (score 1):

One can use strpos() to find the position of [substring] and [/substring] in your string and replace the text with a whitespace via substr_replace()

Comment: This seems like a better approach, because regex is just intimidating and complex to me.

Answer (score 1):

if you do not want to bother with regular expessions:

if you do have the `[shortcode]` tag inside the string, than it is really no problem: just use a nested use of substr:

```
substr($string,0,strpos($string,'[substring]')+11)+substr($string,strpos($string,'[/substring]'),strlen($string))
```

where the first substr cuts the string to the start of the string to cut and the second adds the remaining stuff of the string.

see here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 0):

use regex in php to get rid of it.

```
preg_replace (shortcode, urText, '', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "[shortcode]I want this text removed[/shortcode]"; 
$regex = "#\[shortcode\].*\[\/shortcode\]#i"; 
$replace = "[shortcode][/shortcode]"; 
$newString = preg_replace ($regex, $replace, $string, -1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = "Here's some content [shortcode]I want this text removed[/shortcode] Some more content to be changed to Here's some content [shortcode][/shortcode] Some more content";
print preg_replace('@(\[shortcode\])(.*?)(\[/shortcode\])@', "$1$3", $content);
```

Yields:

Here's some content [shortcode][/shortcode] Some more content to be changed to Here's some content [shortcode][/shortcode] Some more content